If initial ideal is prime, then the ideal is prime (proof verification)
I'm working through Seth Sullivant's "Algebraic Statistics", and one of the exercises is to show that, for an ideal $I$ of a polynomial ring $R=K[p_{1},...,p_{n}]$, if the initial ideal $in_{\prec}(I)$ for some term order $\prec$ is prime, then the ideal $I$ is prime.
My initial thought was to show that the quotient ring $R/I$ is an integral domain, although (1) I don't think this is the expected method to use because quotient rings haven't yet been introduced in the textbook and (2) I'm not sure how to invoke the $in_{\prec}(I)$ being prime assumption. That is, if we assume $\{f+I\}\{g+I\}=\{fg+I\}=I$ for $f,g\neq 0$, I'm not sure how to invoke the assumption that $\{hk+in_{\prec}(I)\}=in_{\prec}(I)\implies h\in in_{\prec}(I)$ or $k\in in_{\prec}(I)$ for $h,k\neq 0$.
Another line of thought is that if

$G=\{g_{1},...,g_{k}\}$ is a Gröebner basis of $I$ with respect to the term order $\prec$ (which exists by applying the Hilbert Basis Theorem) and

$h_{1}h_{2}\in I$ for some $h_{1}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}q_{1,i}g_{i}+r_{1},h_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}q_{2,i}g_{i}+r_{2}\in R$ where no leading term of any polynomial in $G$ divides the leading term of either $r_{1}$ or $r_{2}$ (unless $r_{1}=0$ or $r_{2}=0$),


then $h_{1}h_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}l_{i}g_{i}+r_{1}r_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}q_{i}g_{i}$ for $l_{i},q_{i}\in R$ by the multivariate division algorithm. Since $r_{1}r_{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{k}(q_{i}-l_{i})g_{i}$ is a linear combination of $G$, we have that $r_{1}r_{2}\in I$, implying that $in_{\prec}(r_{1}r_{2})=in_{\prec}(r_{1})in_{\prec}(r_{2})\in in_{\prec}(I)$. Assuming that $in_{\prec}(I)$ is prime, we have that either $in_{\prec}(r_{1})\in in_{\prec}(I)$ or $in_{\prec}(r_{2})\in in_{\prec}(I)$. If we assume without loss of generality that $in_{\prec}(r_{1})\in in_{\prec}(I)$, then $in_{\prec}(r_{1})$ can be written as a linear combination of leading terms of polynomials in $G$ since $\langle in_{\prec}(g)\ |\ g\in G\rangle=in_{\prec}(I)$ by definition of a Gröebner basis. However, by construction of $r_{1}$, either $r_{1}=0$ or no leading term of any polynomial in $G$ can divide the $in_{\prec}(r_{1})$, so we have that $r_{1}=0$ which implies $h_{1}$ is a linear combination of $G$ and is hence in $I$.
I'm very new at working with Gröebner bases; do you

have an idea for proving this statement using quotient rings and/or

spot any flaws in my above argument using a Gröebner basis?


